# generate a mean for a 2-uple with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can generate a table from records like that :

```
ID|Var1|Var2|Measure
1   10   13    10
1   10   15    8
1   15   13    0
    ...
```

One ID can have several Var2 that are identical. How I can generate a mean for each 2-uple ID-Var2 like that :

```
ID|Var2|Mean_Measure
1   13    5
1   14    8
...
2   13    7
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a `GROUP BY` clause to group the rows with the same `ID` and `Var2` together and then the `AVG` function calculates the average:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Var2, AVG(t.Measure) AS Mean_Measure FROM YourTable t GROUP BY t.ID, t.Var2
```

I might add that `GROUP BY` will alter the output of the query quite a bit. It also adds some restrictions on the output. First off - after a group by you can only add expressions in the `SELECT` clause where one the following applies:

1. The expression is part of the `GROUP BY` clause
2. The expression is an application of an aggregate function

In the above example t.ID and t.Var2 exists in the `GROUP BY` clause and AVG(t.Measure) is an application of the aggregate function AVG on t.Measure.

When dealing with `WHERE` clauses and `GROUP BY` there's also some things to note:

1. `WHERE` is applied after the `GROUP BY` this means generally that expressions not in `GROUP BY` cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause
2. If you wish to filter data before the `GROUP BY` use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

I hope this makes sense - and for more and better information on how `GROUP BY`s work - I'd suggest [consulting the MySQL manual on the topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you. However I want the means for each Var 2 concerning every ID. I.e. : it would be for one user (id=12, var2=31, mean_var2= 7)

Comment: Ah - sorry  I assumed that ID was a primary key. See edited answer